# Can't connect to the SharePoint site:

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, connection

I started VS with admin rights, i'm currently in trouble setting up a SharePoint 2010 project.

Today, I installed VS2010 on our new SP 2010 server

But now I'm failing to create a SharePoint project in Visual Studio. The SharePoint Customization Wizard tells me following:

`Cannont connect to the SharePoint site: http://myserver/blah. Make sure that the Site URL is valid, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user as the necessary permissions to access the site.`

As I'm 'quite' sure, that SharePoint is running on the locale system and I'm having no problems browsing SharePoint with my account, I'm wondering what is preventing me to create the project.

Somewhere else I've read that the user, which is running VS2010, needs db_owner rights to the config and admin tables of SP2010, which I've done, unfortunately this didn't affect anything.

Has anybody encountered this problem before? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your SharePoint site using host header? If so can you confirm you have the appropriate host header entry for that site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in the Configuration Wizard needs to be an available SharePoint site so it can deploy the project output.  Try to navigate to this url in a browser or go to an existing SP site and use that url in the Customization Wizard.

Comment: There are not really any steps.  The configuration wizard shows a Url for the local site to use for debugging on the page where you select Sandbox or Farm Solution.  I'm guessing it fails if you click the Validate button.  This url has to be to an existing SP Site.  You can also go to your SP site and get the url of an existing site and paste it here.  Done this way, the site would validate.

Comment: Thanks Rick, okay here is what is happening: its only failing when i try to validate the url and if i just go the browser and go the SP site its working with out any issues and i did try the same url and paste it on the validate text but validate fails.... but strange thing is that, i able to create a project (if i dont click on validate) and when i try to deploy i get the above error message which i posted above.

Comment: The url that works in my project only goes to the site collection or website.  It does not include the page information.  http://server/sites/sitecoll/ or http://server/sites/sitecoll/website/ .  It failed for me if I used http://server/sites/sitecoll/default.aspx

Comment: i am not including any pages for an example my site name is http://sp2010/ and if copy and paste in the browser it works perfectly fine but the same url if i try to validate then it failed.

Comment: Sorry, this resolved my similar issue.  The symptoms are the same but looks like there is a different cause.

Answer (score 0):

Add the user account to SQL Server as sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

See: [Cannot connect to the Sharepoint Site from Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785917/cannot-connect-to-the-sharepoint-site-from-visual-studio-2010)

This issue can be fixed by doing the following :-
 1.
Added myself as the administrator

2.
Added myself to SharePoint Farm Admin Group

3.
Provided DB Owner access to SharePoint Content DB

Answer (score 0):

Add Visual studio process user to the db owners group for sharepoint databases